# How to use the new CompositeFormat class from .NET 8.0?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, .net-8.0

I'm testing migrating a .NET 6.0 application to .NET 8.0, and the following piece of code now throws CA1863 "Use 'CompositeFormat'". But I don't know how.

```cs
private const string DUMP_DIALOGS_TITLE_FORMAT_STRING = "{0} Diagnostic Report";

public static string GetTitle(IProcess currentProcess)
{
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DUMP_DIALOGS_TITLE_FORMAT_STRING, currentProcess.ProcessName);
}
```

The example given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1863) is invalid, since the `StaticField` variable isn't initialized and I don't know what it should be.

If I change the code to

```cs
private static readonly CompositeFormat Format = CompositeFormat.Parse("{0} Diagnostic Report");

public static string GetTitle(IProcess currentProcess)
{
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Format, currentProcess.ProcessName);
}
```

Visual Studio shows a warning that I'm not providing a parameter for the {0} argument, even though everything appears to work as expected (I'm not getting a runtime error with the new code). Is it just that VS code analysis isn't knowing about `CompositeFormat` yet or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't observe this issue in VS 17.8

Comment: Doubling Edgars's observation, here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0 it states that .NET 8 is supported by `Visual Studio 2022 (v17.8)`

Comment: I have v17.9 Preview 1, so I'm assuming it should be supported, too. I have also Resharper installed, which might be the culpit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is just fine:

```
private static readonly CompositeFormat Format = CompositeFormat.Parse("{0} Diagnostic Report");

public static string GetTitle(IProcess currentProcess)
{
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Format, currentProcess.ProcessName);
}
```

The warning comes from ReSharper which currently has only basic support of .NET 8 features (see the [.NET SDK support in JetBrains Rider](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/13244959138834) doc.).

Either install the EAP/RC version ([link](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/nextversion/)) which should have the issue fixed or disable the warning with comment for now:

```
// ReSharper disable once FormatStringProblem
private static readonly CompositeFormat Format = CompositeFormat.Parse("{0} Diagnostic Report");
```

P.S.

Created a [PR for the docs](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/38488) to make example potentially more clear.